# Remove the data before the second repeated specified character in linux

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I have a text file which has some below data:

```
AB-NJCFNJNVNE-802ac94f09314ee
AB-KJNCFVCNNJNWEJJ-e89ae688336716bb
AB-POJKKVCMMMMMJHHGG-9ae6b707a18eb1d03b83c3
AB-QWERTU-55c3375fb1ee8bcd8c491e24b2
```

I need to remove the data before the second hyphen (`-`) and produce another text file with the below output:

```
802ac94f09314ee
e89ae688336716bb
9ae6b707a18eb1d03b83c3
55c3375fb1ee8bcd8c491e24b2
```

I am pretty new to linux and trying `sed` command with unsuccessful attempts for the last couple of hours. How can I get the desired output with sed or any other useful command like `awk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `cut` call:

```
$ cat myfile.txt | cut -d"-" -f3- > myoutput.txt
```

Edit:
Some explanation, as requested in the comments:
`cut` breaks up a string of text to fields according to a given delimiter.
`-d` defines the delimiter, `-` in this case.
`-f` defines which fields to output. In this case, we want to eliminate everything before the second hyphen, or, in other words, return the third field and onwards (`3-`).

The rest of the command is just piping the output. `cat`ing the file into `cut`, and then saving the result to an output file.

Comment: It looks simple. Can you please explain this a little bit? Like I did not get '-f3-'. 'd' stands for delimiter I guess though.....

Comment: @ani0710 I've added some explanation to my answer. Let me know if this clears it up, or if it's still lacking.

Answer (score 2):

Or, using `sed`:

```
cat myfile.txt | sed -e 's/^.\+-//'
```